# Capture Component Label Format in Origin Field of tLogCatcher instead of component name

Tags: talend

I am trying to capture the Label Name of the component in case it fails. When using tLogCatcher it is capturing the failure but printing origin as Component Name example if tRunJob is failing it is printing tRunJob_2.

tRunJob_2 Label Format in View is "ABC_TEST_JOB".

How to capture the Label Format so that in case of debugging I can easily see where that Label Component is considering having 10_ tRunJobs

Answer (score 1):

The label of a component cannot be captured, as it's not in the generated java program, it's just visible in the designer.  Maybe you can keep a mapping between component names and their labels in a tFixedFlowInput and use that as a lookup:

```
         tFixedFlowInput (tRunJob1=ABC, tRunJob2=BCD..)
                 |
                 |
tLogCatcher----tMap----output
```